# }); This bit of code

Tags: wordpress

this bit of code }); has appeared in the very top of my wordpress site. Not really a coder, but looked to see if I could find it in any of the template files and no joy. When you inspect it in Chrome, it is right at the top of the body after all of the css classes.

This is the full code from the page that has the random bit displaying.

[the code I see on inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkR20.png)

Comment: The site probably has been hacked, find the leak fix it and restore the site. Who knows what else might have changed

Comment: Not necessarily. Have you changed any plugins or other settings (example themes) lately?

Comment: There isn't much for anyone to go on to help you with this question. Perhaps you can provide some more details or narrow the problem down a bit more. Try turning on an off various plugins to see if you can isolate the problem.

Comment: Thanks, everyone, I thought hack, but also though plug in. Not my site but one I do SEO work on for someone, so he may have done something. I did try turning off plug ins, but not all as some are vital to site construction, but perhaps I have to try that next